# How to execute an eventhandler, responsible for updating the UI, when declared in the presenter (MVP)

Tags: winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0, mvp

Im trying to implement the MVP pattern and im having some issues with a eventhandler. Originally i declared this in the partial class. Since it contains logic im assuming it should be moved into the presenter?

InvokeRequired/invoke obviously produce errors when i move it to the Presenter though. So apart from leaving the entire method in the view, the only other option i have come up with is to leave the eventhandler in the View, so there wouldnt be any issues with the InvokeRequired etc, but shift the body of the EventHandler, ie the action delegate, into the presenter. I dont know how such a method call would work though as im Using DI atm to communicate between the View -> Presenter, but not sure how to get Presenter -> View.

```
    public void CompletionReportNotifier(object sender, VerificationStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        Action action = () =>
        {
            //Display messages depending on whether it was canceled or not.
            if (e.CarriedOutToCompletion == true)
            {
                string logMessage = string.Format("The data verification operation has been completed and {0} errors were found. Please view the error log for additional information.", inputs.NumberOfErrorsFound.ToString());
                _view.UpdateLog(logMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                _view.UpdateLog("The data verification has failed. Please view the error log for additional information.");
            }

            //...
        };

        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }
```

**EDIT based on ItsMatt's reply**

Presenter Code:

```
    public void CompletionReportNotifier(object sender, VerificationStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        _view.PermanentCsvFileVerificationCancellation = null;

        string logMessage;
        bool inputsVisible = false;

        //Display messages depending on whether it was canceled or not.
        if (e.CarriedOutToCompletion == true)
        {
            logMessage = string.Format("The data verification operation has been completed and {0} errors were found. Please view the error log for additional information.", inputs.NumberOfErrorsFound.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            logMessage = "The data verification has failed. Please view the error log for additional information.";
        }

        //Assign values to parameters depending on if it failed or errors were encountered.
        if (e.CarriedOutToCompletion != true || inputs.NumberOfErrorsFound > 0)
        {
            inputsVisible = true;
            _view.VerificationCompleted = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _view.VerificationCompleted = true;
        }

        _view.UIUpdate(logMessage, inputsVisible);
    }
```

View Code:

```
    public void UIUpdate(string logMessage, bool inputsVisible)
    {
        Action action = () =>
        {
            UpdateLog(logMessage);
            AccessToCsvFileVerificationInputs(inputsVisible);
            btnDataVerification.Text = "Verify Data";
            DisplayBusyMouseCursor(false);
            VerifyingData = false;
        };
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, you're essentially - at least from what I can see in the code snippet - determining what log message string to ultimately display to the user, right?

So what about about using `Func` rather than `Action`?  That way you could create your `Func` delegate on the presenter side with whatever logic you've got in there, have it create the logMessage and return it when the view executes it.

This would keep your logic on the presenter side and the particulars about the UI on the UI side.  Whether you need to call Invoke is really a UI concern, not a concern of the presenter, right?  I'm thinking you just stick that Invoke code in the UI and have it execute the Func passed to it.

I was thinking something like this:

```
public void CompletionReportNotifier(object sender, VerificationStatusEventArgs e)
{
    Func<string> func = () =>
    {
        string logMessage = string.empty;

        //Display messages depending on whether it was canceled or not.
        if (e.CarriedOutToCompletion == true)
        {
            logMessage = 
                    string.Format("The data verification operation has been completed and {0} errors were found. Please view the error log for additional information.",
                    inputs.NumberOfErrorsFound.ToString());
       }
        else
        {
            logMessage ="The data verification has failed. Please view the error log for additional information.";
        }

        return logMessage;
    };
    _view.UpdateLog(func);
}
```

And in the view something like

```
public void UpdateLog(Func func)
{
   if (InvokeRequired) 
   {
      someControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
      {
         Invoke(whateverUi.Text = func());
      }));  
   }
   else
      whateverUi.Text = func();
}
```

So as far as the Presenter knows, it has some IView (or however you do things - I was assuming the Presenter has an IView but whatever) that has an UpdateLog method on it that can be called by passing it a Func argument.

As far as the View knows, its UpdateLog method gets called by somebody and whatever that Func outputs gets used however the UI uses it.  In my example, I just set the text of some control to the result.  If Invoke needs to be called, it is.

Comment: Morning ItsMatt, thanks for taking the time to reply (+1 for your comment about func, will look into that). I guess id trimmed down the code a little too much, sorry. It was also responsible for setting whether certain user inputs were still visible or not + setting one or two properties (see edit to original question). Ive taken ur idea though and tried to split the logmessage and the bool determining whether the inputs are visible or not into the Presenter. It then just calls the UIUpdate method in the View via the View's Interface. Is this acceptable? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Hey @HansRudel - glad to give you my opinion.:)  So, yes I think that's better.  The MVP pattern is really about putting all the "tell the UI to do X" stuff in the presenter and then letting the view deal with view-specific implementation stuff.  Meaning, essentially, that you should be able to swap out the View with a new  View and have little pain in doing so.  Definitely the fact that you might need to call Invoke is a View concern.  The fact that you need to update the UI is a Presenter concern.

Comment: Aside - My particular approach is usually to communicate from the View to the Presenter via events and to inject the View into the Presenter.  There are other ways but I like that approach personally.

Comment: Im using the same approach atm as im not familar with another/it seems to make sense atm. Now just need to get the specifics of how to unit test methods in the presenter (assuming i havent poorly engineered something else). Thanks again for ur help, the guidance i get from ppl like urself is invaluable!